# Edit Functionality in GridView Works Only in the First Row

Tags: c#, asp.net

My Insert, and Delete functionality works fine but i am having an issue with the Edit functionality.  The Edit functionality works only on the first line of the row but if i try to edit the 2nd or the 3rd row then
i get this error:
"Must declare the scalar variable "@Post_ID"
Here is my code:

```
GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)GridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex];
        int id = Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
        TextBox date = (TextBox)row.FindControl("date");

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.CommandText =    "update t_your_table " +
                             "set " +                                 
                             "date = @date, " +             
                             " time = @time  where id = @ID "                             


    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = id;           
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@date", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = date.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

You are hard-coding the row in this code:

```
TextBox myTextBox11 = GV_InlineEditing.Rows[0].FindControl("GV_Post_ID") as TextBox;
```

`.Rows[0]` will always find the first row, regardless of status.  You would want to look at the row you are editing, using the [EditIndex property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.editindex.aspx).

Comment: thanks. i updated and fixed the issue.  pls. look the updated code